# Spring Boot Cache Redis + Jackson. Serialize value as JSON. Cannot read - no session

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, jackson-databind

Using spring boot latest with jpa + caching. For caching used Redis.

`pom` looks like this:

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I'm storing a history record in cache, which has the next structure:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
@ToString
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Builder.Default
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentId")
    @Builder.Default
    private List<Entity1Entry> history = new ArrayList<>();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Builder.Default
    private Date created = new Date();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Builder.Default
    private Date updated = new Date();
}
```

Decided to try if I could change things from `Serializable` to JSON and got stuck at that.

My config:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

 
        @Bean
    public CacheManager redisCacheManager(@Value("${spring.cache.ttl}") Integer ttl,
                                          RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager =  RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder
                .fromConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(
                        RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                                .entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(ttl))
//                                .serializeValuesWith(getJsonSerializer())
                                .disableCachingNullValues()
                )
                .transactionAware()
                .build();
        return cacheManager;

    }
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration defaultCacheConfig() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()))
//                .serializeValuesWith(getJsonSerializer())
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(7))
                ;
    }

    private RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair getJsonSerializer() {
        GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer jsonRedisSerializer = genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
        return RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(jsonRedisSerializer);
    }

    private GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = objectMapper();
        return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper);
    }


    private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN);
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

        objectMapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Ignore the commented out parts to be commented out - it been a 3 hour fight so far, so I'm trying everything.

The problem I'm getting is that I can't read the record from `@Cacheable`, always failing with a `Could not read JSON: No session` when trying to read the `Entity1` with its list entity.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `@Cacheable` to cache database entities, integrate that with your JPA provider through the 2nd level cache instead. Unrelated (slightly) don't use `@Data` with JPA as it will generate an equals/hashCode that isn't suitable for JPA/managed entities.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you please point me to an article on that approach? Google made me believe that `@Cacheable` was the way.

Comment: Assuming you are using HIbernate I suggest a read on the 2nd level caching and how to enable and configure it especially for Redis (as I have no idea how to to that).